# End game mercenary equipment?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, fantasy-life

I would like to know how to get the **'ULTIMATE' Great-Sword** for the mercenary in Fantasy Life, I am a Legend level and I don't know what other lives I need to master to unlock the sword. Any advice? Which lives do I need to master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the [Crescent Blade](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Crescent_Blade) (the highest attack greatsword in the non-[DLC Fantasy Life](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Origin_Island)) you must master the [Mercenary](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Mercenary), [Angler](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Angler), and [Tailor](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Tailor) classes, then pay a visit to the [pirate ship](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Ship%27s_Cabin) that you met with [Olivia](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Olivia_Pescado) in. When you enter the captain's quarters, you will see a [treasure chest](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Chests#Pirate_King.27s_Treasure) off to your left. After you have mastered the aforementioned classes the chest will be open-able and within it you will find the Crescent Blade along with the [Buccaneer's Hat](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Buccaneer%27s_Hat), [Buccaneer's Coat](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Buccaneer%27s_Coat), [Buccaneer's Bottoms](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Buccaneer%27s_Bottoms), [Buccaneer's Boots](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Buccaneer%27s_Boots).

Source: Personal play tagged with [The Fantasy Life Wiki](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/) for specifics and links.

Comment: Oh and if you haven't gotten it already, I suggest going to the king during the day to get your Mercenary outfit as well.